# Elmah Redirects to its own default Error Page And not to Custom page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, custom-error-pages

Hi i am using MVC5+Elmah
**My Web.Config has**

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />

<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorMgmt/Error/General"></customErrors>
```

**Filter Config has**

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

**in Controller Action i have**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("Testing ELMAH");            
    }
```

Now when this action is executed ELMAH take me to its own default error page & not the one which i configured in customerrors. How can i cofigure elmah so that it redirects to ErrorMgmt/Error/General & not its own view. Please help